# How to get the program in C# to react to user input

Tags: c#, while-loop, readline

So below is the code I have.  When i hit 5 I have to hit enter 5 times to get the program to write the line and pressing 6 doesn't work at all.  Any solution would be appreciated.

```
            Boolean keepRunning = true;
            while (keepRunning = true)
            {
                if (Console.ReadLine() == "1")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Still running");
                }
                else if (Console.ReadLine() == "2")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Still running2");
                }
                else if (Console.ReadLine() == "3")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Still running3");
                }
                else if (Console.ReadLine() == "4")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Still running4");
                }
                else if (Console.ReadLine() == "5")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Still running5");
                }
                else if (Console.ReadLine() == "6")
                {
                    keepRunning = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: A helpful question to ask yourself, whenever your code doesn't do what you expect, is 'what assumptions am I making in this code?' Your faulty assumption is what `Console.ReadLine()` does (and what `keepRunning = true` does). Reading the docs may help.

Comment: `Console.Readline()` pause the program there until a key is pressed. Here it goes into first `if` and wait for a key press. If it's not 1 it goes in the second `else...if` and check the key again. You need to read only once before like in @MightyBadaboom solution

Comment: ReadLine() expects the user to hit enter before continue, so this won't be valid for just one keystroke. Anyway, using ReadLine in each single instruction does not make sense, since the program will stop in each condition until a key is entered: The first time it expects "1", so if you enter any other key, you will go the next linked condition, which expects for "2" and so on...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're waiting for an enter with each `Console.ReadLine();`. Read the input only once and then decide what to do.

And you should change your while condition to `keepRunning == true`. With your current version you set `keepRunning` to `true` in your condition and that's why it seems like "6" is not working ;)

```
Boolean keepRunning = true;
while (keepRunning == true)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (input == "1")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Still running");
    }
    else if (input == "2")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Still running2");
    }
    else if (input == "3")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Still running3");
    }
    else if (input == "4")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Still running4");
    }
    else if (input == "5")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Still running5");
    }
    else if (input == "6")
    {
        keepRunning = false;
    }
}
```

You can use a switch statement to make it even better.

```
switch(input)
{
    case "1":
        Console.WriteLine("Still running");
        break;
    case "2":
        Console.WriteLine("Still running");
        break;
    case "3":
        Console.WriteLine("Still running");
        break;
    case "4":
        Console.WriteLine("Still running");
        break;
    case "5":
        Console.WriteLine("Still running");
        break;
    case "6":
        keepRunning = false;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: @Caleb You're welcome. And thanks for accepting the answer in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should read line only one-time per iteration. See example below:

```
string readLine = "";
Boolean keepRunning = true;
while (keepRunning)
{
    readLine= Console.ReadLine();
    switch readLine{
        case "1":
            Console.WriteLine("Still running");
            break;
        case "2":
            Console.WriteLine("Still running2");
            break;
        case "3":
            Console.WriteLine("Still running3");
            break;
        case "4":
            Console.WriteLine("Still running4");
            break;
        case "5":
            Console.WriteLine("Still running5");
            break;
        case "6":
            keepRunning = false;
            break;
    }
}
```